# meaning of "if part of $A$ iff $B$"?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, notation

Here I am just wondering if there is some generally accepted convention (or if I have if and only if backwards?)

Specifically, I often see things like "THM: $A$ iff $B$" and then "PF (if part): Assume $A$. Show that $B$ is true"

That is, I often see people calling the "if" part of "A iff B" $A\implies B$. **But I thought $A$ if $B$ means $B\implies A$** ? (as in If B is true then A must be true)

I realize that "A iff B" implies "B iff A". So if people often take $A\implies B$ to be the "if part of "A iff B", does than mean that it is convention to prove "A iff B" as "B iff A", or are people just using confusing notation?

Comment: A iff B is usually written $A \leftrightarrow B$, meaning indeed what you said. You usually prove it by proving both $A \rightarrow B$ _and_ $B \rightarrow A$. You can also prove it by noting that "A iff B" means that if A is true, then B is true _and_ that if A is false, B is false. That is in contrast to "if A then B" which means if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true--you do not need to consider the case that $A$ is false.

Comment: @Jared Thanks, but I'm not sure that answers my question (if it does then I am misunderstanding you) I am asking that, if someone wants to prove "$A \leftrightarrow B$", is there a convention for which direction is the "if direction" (since $A$ iff $B$ is equivalent to $B$ iff $A$")

Comment: @user106860 No, you have it right. "$A$ iff $B$" means "$A$ if and only if $B$", and if we drop the "and only if" part producing "$A$ if $B$", that indeed means $B\implies A$. Personally, I usually write something like "**Proof**: ($\Rightarrow$ direction) ... ($\Leftarrow$ direction) ..." or I may omit the "direction". This is generally unambiguous and compact and nicely separates the two cases visually.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you. I also use ($\implies$ direction) (and the reverse). I just feel like I have come across $A\implies B$ being called the "if" direction enough times to make me wonder if there is a convention (of taking "A iff B" to mean "B is necessary and sufficient for A" or something).

Comment: @user106860 There is a bit of "english" confusion going on here I think. "A if B" is equivalent to "If B then A", which is written $B \implies A$ (or $B \rightarrow A$...the $\implies$ vs. $\rightarrow$ is more a matter of accepted style, I think). So perhaps I misspoke by saying "A iff B" means $A \iff B$, when, technically it should be $B \iff A$ (but these statements _are_ indeed equivalent, particularly when proving the statement).

Comment: @user106860: as Derek Elkins says, you are right. What you are seeing is sloppy writing. Occasionally you will also see the two parts of the "iff"  proof labelled "necessity" and "sufficiency", which is also unhelpful (unless the statement being proved has been stated as "$A$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $B$" rather than $A$ iff $B$). In your own writing, I recommend doing as Derek suggests and labelling the two parts with $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ or with "left to right" and "right to left".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an error.  There is a natural tendency to think of $A\Rightarrow B$ as the "first part" of $A\Leftrightarrow B$, and also a natural tendency to think of "if" as the "first part" of "if and only if".  Since these conflict, people sometimes erroneously identify which part of $A\Leftrightarrow B$ is "if" and which part is "only if".